# How can I share my YouTube clip anonymously?

Tags: gmail, google, youtube, anonymous

I have uploaded a video to YouTube and I want to share it without revealing my YouTube identity. Meaning I don't want people to see other videos of mine or my YouTube or Gmail username.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are over thinking this one. You should create a second account. It would allow you to keep them separated. You can be logged into more than one account on youtube at a time.

Comment: Then I'll have to create an account to each video I want to show seperatly

Comment: If you don't want any of them connected to any other video or your personal information, I unfortunately don't see a way around creating multiple accounts.

Recently Youtube has been asking it's user base to use their real names. Also, Youtube keeps record of your IP address when you upload. So if this whistleblower activity, you might want to post after logging into a VPN or public proxy.